# How to delay without time.sleep?

Tags: python, time, tkinter, sleep

I'm using Python with Tkinter to create a game. When the game ends, I'm trying to display "Game Over", which I inserted as an image, and after that by a few seconds I'd like to put another image.  I've tried to put `time.sleep(2)` in between but it hasn't worked, it stops right after game over.

Comment: Can you paste your code please?

Comment: look at the tkinter `after` function http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.after-method

Comment: Have you tried using `update()` method on `master` just after the `time.sleep(2)` statement?

Comment: what is the update() method?

Answer (score 2):

Don't think "delay", think "schedule". You can create the "game over" screen like normal, and use `after` to schedule some action. This allows the GUI to continue to respond to events.

The following example destroys the "game over" window in two seconds, but you could easily just swap out images, change text, change colors, etc.

```
import Tkinter as tk

def gameover():
   top = tk.Toplevel(root)
   label = tk.Label(top, text="Game over!")
   label.pack(padx=20, pady=20, expand=True)
   top.after(2000, top.destroy)

root = tk.Tk()
button = tk.Button(root, text='Click to simulate "game over"', command=gameover)
button.pack(padx=20, pady=20)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: It just doesn't seem to work. I just created an image on the screen when the game ends, and i need it to create another one later. I did actually try with "after" but wanting to end it after the first time i think it didn't process it. I'm sorry I'm still a beginner.